# Include count of all visits to a given host alongside each visit record in Firefox history

Tags: sql, sqlite, firefox

Firefox has two history tables, `moz_historyvisits` and `moz_places`.

```
moz_historyvisits
| place_id | visit_date |

moz_places
| id       | url        | title      | rev_host    | visit_count |
```

I want a result set as follows:

```
| id       | url        | title      | visit_count | visit_date  | rev_host    | host_visit_count|
... for all history_visits.
```

The code I have currently:

```
select moz_historyvisits.id,
moz_places.url,
moz_places.title,
moz_places.visit_count,
datetime((moz_historyvisits.visit_date/1000000), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as thedate,
moz_places.rev_host,
(select count('x') from moz_places as ct where ct.rev_host = moz_places.rev_host) as host_visit_count
from moz_places, moz_historyvisits
where moz_historyvisits.place_id = moz_places.id
order by thedate DESC;
```

The problem is that `host_visit_count` is too low. I believe I am just counting the unique URLs in `moz_places` and not the total number of visits to a given host. How do I accomplish this tabulation across tables, while still retaining a complete list of visits?

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that you are counting just the number of places in the places table rather than the number of visits.  You can fix this by changing the table used in the subquery.

I am also fixing your query to use proper join notation and table aliases:

```
select hv.id, p.url, p.title, p.visit_count,
       datetime((hv.visit_date/1000000), 'unixepoch', 'localtime') as thedate, 
       p.rev_host,
       (select count(*)
        from moz_historyvisits hv1
        where hv1.place_id = hv.place_id
       ) as host_visit_count
from moz_places p join
     moz_historyvisits hv
     on hv.place_id = p.id
order by thedate DESC;
```

Comment: Hmm... I'm seeing `visit_count=host_visit_count` whereas what I'm looking for is the count of all visits to a given host.